# Find quantity of elements in group with given order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> Let $G = ( \mathbb { Z } / 133 \mathbb { Z } ) ^ { \times }$ be the
>   group of units of the ring $\mathbb { Z } / 133 \mathbb { Z }$ . Find
>   the number of elements of $G$ of order $9 .$

133 cannot be divided by 9. So what is the solution to the problem? Or my consideration is too simple to realize the problem precisely?

Comment: The order of $G$ is not $133$, the order of $\Bbb Z/133\Bbb Z$ is $133$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I am sorry but I wonder 1.Why $G$ has 108 elements as mentioned in the answer below?  2. Is there a universal solution for problem like this?

Comment: Not every element of $\Bbb Z/\Bbb 133\Bbb Z$ is a unit. The units are those coprime to $133$ (inverse of $k$ mod $n$ exists iff $k$ is coprime to $n$). The order of the group of units is given by $\phi(133)=\phi(7\times 19)=6\times 18=108$ where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* 
$
( \mathbb { Z } / 133 \mathbb { Z } ) ^ { \times }
\cong
( \mathbb { Z } / 7 \mathbb { Z } ) ^ { \times }
\times
( \mathbb { Z } / 19 \mathbb { Z } ) ^ { \times }
\cong
C_6 \times C_{18}
$

Answer (score 0):

The fact that $9\nmid133$ is irrelevant here, since the group $\mathbb{Z}_{133}^\times$ has $108$ elements. Since $9\mid108$, Lagrange's theorem is not an obstacle to the existence of elements of order $9$.